# how to get Index and String from ListView on ArrayAdapter class

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-view

i m creating webservice application. it has ArrayAdapter class that is present the web data to Listview. and i want to get index of selected Listview Item and send the index value to next activity to do other task. but i m not able to get Index from ListView. **ListView id is default Android API id**

I used almost everything like **setOnItemSelectedListener**  and **setOnClickListener** **OnItemSelectedListener** but did not work

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

        initView();   
    }

    private void initView() {
        // show progress dialog
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...");

        String url = "xxxxxxxx";
        // json class doing background data processing  
        FetchDataTask task = new FetchDataTask(this);
        task.execute(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFetchComplete(List<Application> data) {
        // dismiss the progress dialog
        if(dialog != null)  dialog.dismiss();
        // create new adapter
     ApplicationAdapter adapter = new ApplicationAdapter(this, data);
        // set the adapter to list
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);        

         }
```

THIS IS ArrayAdapter class

```
public class ApplicationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Application>  implements OnItemClickListener{
    private List<Application> items;
    ListView listview;
    public ApplicationAdapter(Context context, List<Application> items) {
        super(context, R.layout.app_custom_list, items);
        this.items = items;

        MainActivity.lv.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() 
        {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View childView, int position, long id) 
            {
                String text = ((TextView)childView.getTag()).toString();
             Log.d("index",text);
            }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) 
            {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        if(v == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = li.inflate(R.layout.app_custom_list, null);            
        }

        Application app = items.get(position);

        if(app != null) {
            ImageView icon = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.appIcon);



                for(int i=1; i<=5; i++) {
                    ImageView iv = new ImageView(getContext());

                    if(i <= app.getRating()) {
                        iv.setImageDrawable(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.start_checked));
                    }
                    else {                
                        iv.setImageDrawable(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.start_unchecked));
                    }

                    ratingCntr.addView(iv);
                }
            }
        }

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        String[] lv_arr = null;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String itemname = lv_arr[position];
        Log.d("string from ListView",itemname);


    }
}
```

Please help me to get Index of Selected Item of ListView. if anyone can suggest me what should i use , i will be grateful to them

thanks in Advance

Comment: What exactly do you not work with onItemSelected, onItemClick? But in general, you oddly create listener. As the bud using static variables. Look at that, if [this guide](http://androidexample.com/Create_A_Simple_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=65&aaid=90)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at the bottom of `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {` add

```
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

      //get position index of item here. 

       String indexid = String.valueOf(position);  

       //and do whatever afterwards.                              


                        });

                    }
```

and remove `public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, .......` in your adapter

Comment: lv is declare in MainActivity as ListView and i edit lv to `MainActivity.lv`and it gives **nullPointerExpection** on `onItemClick  ` could please identity
@Tasos

Comment: Cool dude, it is working now @Tasos  you made my day

Comment: I have a TextView inside the array adapter and I would like to fire off the onclick for the item element, not the element itself. How can I do that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37071016/how-to-share-by-clicking-on-an-element-inside-the-card-array-adapter